# Highpoint 620 driver in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, compiling

I am running the latest Ubuntu version at the moment (with the 3.11 kernel)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RocketRaid is what I used, however I then get the following error upon making the file...

```
root@michael-server:/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/os_linux.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.o
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c: In function ‘s                                                                                        csicmd_buf_put’:
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:482:55: error:                                                                                         macro "kunmap_atomic" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
  kunmap_atomic((char *)buf - sg->offset, HPT_KMAP_TYPE);
                                                       ^
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:482:2: error: ‘                                                                                        kunmap_atomic’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  kunmap_atomic((char *)buf - sg->offset, HPT_KMAP_TYPE);
  ^
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:482:2: note: ea                                                                                        ch undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c: At top level:
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:2111:2: error:                                                                                         unknown field ‘proc_info’ specified in initializer
  proc_info:               hpt_proc_info26,
  ^
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:2111:2: warning                                                                                        : initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.c:2111:2: warning                                                                                        : (near initialization for ‘driver_template.proc_dir’) [enabled by default]
make[2]: *** [/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build/osm_linux.o]                                                                                         Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux/.build] Erro                                                                                        r 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
make: *** [rr62x.ko] Error 2
root@michael-server:/tmp/rr62x-linux-src-v1.2/product/rr62x/linux# cd /tmp
```

Would someone be so kind to assist me in what is wrong in this? Will this also allow me to use the SATA ports as a SATA extender? (I've got a fantec (e)-sata extender hence the question...)

Maybe someone can just provide the files as needed? (so all I basically have to do, is place the files in the correct folder (I am sure its something I CAN handle :)) and be done /w it...

Answer (score 0):

The [driver download page](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_rr600-download.htm) does say:

> **Supported Linux Kernel version** Up to Kernel v3.6

Until they've updated it, I think you're limited on version of Kernel. New Kernels aren't just a set of new numbers. Things get moved around. The way things work changes.

---

That said, [people have been working on patches](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1899544&page=2). If you do follow that (rather than using a supported kernel) make sure you pick the right version.

Comment: Updated and simplified procedure for Ubuntu 13.04 or later

This procedure will work for both RAID and JBOD configurations, and includes dkms and the latest RocketRaid 62x, 64x, 64xl drivers (thank you to the brave sysadmins who have preceded me on this page).   
Atleast this is what I get from the site

How does this patching work? I am quite new to this concept in the linux world...

I reckon, on a side note that highpoint itself does no longer maintain the driver?